# Reload the same javascript file when loading each static page

Tags: javascript

I have a few static html pages. All these pages have the following

```
<script src="my-javascript.js"></script>
```

I don't want the browser to cache the javascript file, and I want it to get reloaded at page load for each page.

After online search, I found that this trick: adding the following to each page

```
<script src="my-javascript.js?p=changing_value"></script>
```

If this is going to work, how can I generate the "changing_value" in a static html page (not PHP, JSP, etc.).

Or some other solutions to force reload the javascript file at each page load for all pages?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I dont have access to server configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After online search, I found that this trick: adding the following to each page

A much better solution is to use caching headers to tell the browser not to cache the file. Configure your server to serve that file with:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: -1
```

Those are the basic ones, anyway.

> If this is going to work, how can I generate the "changing_value" in a static html page (not PHP, JSP, etc.).

If you want to go the query string route, though, just for completeness:

You can get a random value from `Math.random()`, or [as Hemadeus points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30787226/157247), use a timestamp value.

If you need the script load to be blocking (like script tags normally are), this is one of the few remaining use cases for `document.write`:

```
<script>
document.write('<script src="my-javascript.js?' + Math.random() + '"><\/script>');
</script>
```

*(Or replace `Math.random()` with `Date.now()` to use a timestamp)*

If you don't need it to be blocking, then creating the element with `createElement` is probably cleaner:

```
<script>
(function() {
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.src =  "my-javascript.js?" + Math.random();
    document.querySelector("head").appendChild(s);
})();
</script>
```

---

Old browsers won't have `Date.now`. You can get the same value from `new Date().getTime()`.

Comment: Unfortunately, configuring the server is beyond my access. I have to do it differently. Thanks for your input!

Comment: @curious1: I added an example of using the query string trick as well.

Comment: T.J. Crowder, thanks so much for your solution, which is not only working, but also teaching me a few other things. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You could generate the changing_value using a Javascript timestamp. 
so you will always have a new version of the js file.